# Show .bin video from web in a videoView/webView

Tags: java, android, binary, mp4

I have a camera that streams a .bin video to a website, and I want to show this video in my android app.

For some reason it doesnt show even in a WebView, what can I do to resolve this? I tried using the Picasso library, didnt work. I also tried something like this, which also didnt work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
   
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView); 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri); 
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView); 
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView); 
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController); 
        videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, for anyone interested here is the code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(getIP.url);
                try {
                    //http parametre
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(1000 * 5);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();

                        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                        String data;
                        int len;
                        byte[] buffer;

                        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if (data.contains("Content-Type:")) {
                                data = br.readLine();
                                len = Integer.parseInt(data.split(":")[1].trim());
                                bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                                buffer = new byte[len];

                                int t = 0;
                                while (t < len) {
                                    t += bis.read(buffer, t, len - t);
                                }

                                Bytes2ImageFile(buffer, getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/0A.jpg");
                                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/0A.jpg");
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        //connectButton.setText("OFF");
                                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();}

                    if (fos != null) {
                        fos.close();}

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```